# trouble with transpose in pd.read_csv

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have a data in a CSV file structured like this

```
Installation    Manufacturing   Sales & Distribution    Project Development Other
          43,934           24,916                 11,744        -               12,908 
          52,503           24,064                 17,722        -               5,948 
          57,177           29,742                 16,005        7,988           8,105 
          69,658           29,851                 19,771        12,169          11,248 
          97,031           32,490                 20,185        15,112          8,989 
          119,931          30,282                 24,377        22,452          11,816 
          137,133          38,121                 32,147        34,400          18,274 
          154,175          40,434                 39,387        34,227          18,111
```

I want to skip the header and transpose the list like this

```
43934   52503   57177   69658   97031   119931  137133  154175
24916   24064   29742   29851   32490   30282   38121   40434
11744   17722   16005   19771   20185   24377   32147   39387
0   0   7988    12169   15112   22452   34400   34227
12908   5948    8105    11248   8989    11816   18274   18111
```

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd 
import csv

FileName = "C:/Users/kesid/Documents/Pthon/Pthon.csv"
data = pd.read_csv(FileName, header= None)
data = list(map(list, zip(*data)))
print(data)
```

I am getting the error "TypeError: zip argument #1 must support iteration". Any help much appreciated.

Comment: `pd.read_csv(FileName,header=None,skiprows=[0]).T` ??

Comment: perfect!! it works. Do you know how we can turn off the index (0,1,2,3,4) at the column level? or both column and row-level?

Comment: `pd.read_csv(FileName,header=None,skiprows=[0]).T.to_numpy()` ?? check answer

Comment: thanks it works. However, the issue is i want to list them with data = list(zip(data)). when I use with index then it only shows [0,1,2,3,4] . when I use your code without index it works but i see [(array([ 43934,  52503,  57177,  69658,  97031, 119931, 137133, 154175],
      dtype=int64),), (array([24916, 24064, 29742, 29851, 32490, 30282, 38121, 40434], How can I avoid these "Arrary" ot dtype words and simply want to have list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can *read_csv* in "normal" mode:

```
df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
```

(colum names will be dropper later).

Start processing from replacing *NaN* with *0*:

```
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

Then use either `df.values.T` or `df.values.T.tolist()`, whatever
better suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use skiprows=[0] to skip reading the first row and use .T to transpose

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, skiprows=[0], header=None).T
```